# How would one detect a property of type "InvalidOperationException" within a collection?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, com, ms-office, add-in

Consider the following vb.net code for an office add-in (for access):

```
td = db.TableDefs(objectName)
For Each fld In td.Fields
    For Each fldprp In fld.Properties

        Debug.Print(fldprp.Value.ToString())

    Next
Next
```

the variable "db" is a .net representation of the access vba return result from "Application.CurrentDB()". "td" is of type "DAO.TableDefClass".

This code throws an exception of type "InvalidOperationException" when the value of the fldprp.value property cannot be determined (in Visual Studio, it shows the value as {"Invalid Operation."} in the watch window). fldprp.name, however, is available.

There are only a few properties which this occurs on. I'd like to be able to loop through all the fld.properties and output the values, but ONLY if it is not an exception.

I am pretty sure why it is happening (certain properties are not available in this context). What I need to know is how to detect this at run-time so i can skip the property.

I can't seem to find a solution that will work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get around this using a try...catch block with an empty catch block, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the body of the inner loop, put this at the top:

```
If TypeOf fldprp Is InvalidOperationException Then Continue
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18%28VS.80%29.aspx

I don't know your specific situation, but what I would suggest is using an explicit filter for the object types you *want* to include instead of filtering *out* the ones you don't want to include.